# Mobx injector store not available

Tags: react-native, mobx-react

I try do that Store objet ProviderStore.ts.

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';

import { IUser } from './../interfaces/user.interface';

export class ProviderState {
    constructor(provider: IUser){
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    @observable public provider: IUser;

    @action
    public setProvider(provider: IUser) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }
}
```

After that I want to get a provider.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';

import { ProviderState } from './../states/provider.state';
import { API_URL } from './../../env.json';

export const DetailsScreen = inject('ProviderState')(observer((props: any) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const runEffects = async () => {
            const url = `${API_URL}/company/1`;
            const res = await Http.get(url);

            props.ProviderState.setProvider(res);
        };
        runEffects();
    }, []);

    return (
       <Provider providerState={ProviderState}>
            <View style={styles.body}>
                <MessageComponent textValue={props.ProviderState.naame} />
            </View>
       </Provider>
    );
}));
```

But I get an error

> Error: MobX observer: Store 'ProviderStore' is not available! Make sure it is provided by some Provider

I myself could not find the error. Where could I make a mistake?

Comment: To use `inject` you need to also use `<Provider/>` top-level component, and actually pass stores to it. The error is about `UserStore`, and you are not using it in your snippets, so they does not make sense. Are you sure `UserStore` is provided though?

Comment: @Danila I have several stores and I wrote a mistake from the wrong store

Comment: @Danila I did as you said, but the error remained

Comment: You can't do that `<Provider providerState={ProviderState}>` inside component which is wrapped in inject. It need to be higher up, in parent component, or even top-level component of the whole app.

Comment: Cases also don't match `providerState` -> `ProviderState`. It also needs to be an instance, not just class constructor